# Maximum headphone volume very low on ubuntu 18.04

Tags: 18.04, sound, bluetooth, pulseaudio, headphones

My headphones are the apple airpods and I am using ubuntu on the asus vivobook f510ua.
The volume is very low even on maximum. This happened a few weeks ago and it was back to normal volume until today when it became quiet again.
Before you ask, I have already:
-restarted pulseaudio and alsamixer
-reinstalled pulseaudio and alsamixer
-rebooted my computer
-removed and readded my airpods as a bluetooth device
-set all the alsamixer controls to max
-set the sound settings to above 100% (the sound is at 153% now)
-installed pavucontrol
-ran apt-get update and apt-get upgrade

The test speakers option in my settings did not work so I installed libcanberra-pulse and now that works but the sound is still low volume.

Any ideas on how to fix this?

Comment: Facing the same issue

Answer (score 0):

I have applied this for my Airpods:

Edit

`sudo nano /lib/systemd/system/bluetooth.service`

and change

`ExecStart=/usr/lib/bluetooth/bluetoothd`

to

`ExecStart=/usr/lib/bluetooth/bluetoothd` **--noplugin=avrcp**

and run

```
sudo systemctl daemon-reload
sudo systemctl restart bluetooth
```